# A family has $10$ children. What is the probability that they have more girls than boys, given that at least two of the children are boys?

Tags: probability

A family has $10$ children. What is the probability that they have more girls than boys, given that at least two of the children are boys?

If it was the case for 3 children then I could have simply find all the combinations and then from that it becomes very easy but for such a big case how am I supposed to find the answer?

Comment: If exactly $2$ of the children are boys, and we assume every child is either a girl or a boy, then we have $10 - 2 = 8$ girls, so the probability is $1$. Either this is a trick question, or we're missing something.

Comment: Sorry?  If exactly two are boys then exactly eight are girls.  What am I missing?

Comment: Is it possible you meant:  "at least two are boys"?

Comment: I think you guys are having trouble understanding the question. Given that 2 of 10 are boys. Now there are 8 places left. Of these 8 places 8 of them can be girls and 7 of them can be girls and 1 boy and 6 girls 2 boys. Now we have to find the probability of the cases happening.

Comment: Then you mean *at least* two are boys, like lulu suggested.

Comment: Right.  So it's "at least" two boys, not "exactly" two boys as you wrote.  In that case, the only winning scenarios are exactly $6,7,8$ girls.  Just compute the probability of each of those cases (and I do mean "exactly", not "at least").

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the $2^{10}=1024$ possible gender assignments, the restriction rules out those $11$ with one or no boy. These removed cases happen to be "favorable" cases, i.e., with more girls than boys. Moreover, there are ${10\choose 5}$ possible cases of a tie, and *usually* half of the rest would be favorable. Hence the desired probability is
$$\frac{\frac12(2^{10}-{10\choose 5})-11}{2^{10}-11}=\frac{375}{1013}\approx 0.37 $$

Comment: Thank you. How did you calculate there are 11 cases with one or no boys?

Comment: Okay got it. C(10, 1) + C(10, 0) right? Thanks!